# randomly subtract desired percentage from a array using php

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have a `array` which contains `40` elements like this

```
$i = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11',
'12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24',
'25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35',
'36','37','38','39','40');
```

now i have `4` variations like `5%, 10%, 15%, 20%`

The requirement is i need to take `array values` randomly after subtracting the desired `variation`.

Lets say i used `5%` variation so i need to separate `5%` from the array ie `2` elements i need to remove randomly from the array and keep the rest `38` element in a new `array` randomly.so both the resulted `array` as well subtracted elements need to be in two different `array`.

I need a function with two parameter ie one is `variation` and another is required `array` ie resultant `array` or subtracted elements `array`.

This same sequence follows to all other variations.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: jon i need the function in php which can return me the desired value i.e desired array .. did you read it properly

Comment: Dear OP. You wrote what you need, not what you've tried and where you're stuck. This isn't a coding service where you write what you need and we'll just code it for you.

Comment: @sAnS I did read it. And as Magnus points out, it's a set of requirements, not a question. We won't do your work for you.

Comment: Magnus i am helping more than coding service here in SO. I don't feel i am doing coding service. i stuck up in larger prototype this is just small glimpse

Comment: @sAnS i've created my own function for doing this. For a hint: set a new array = old array, splice it x times which is calculated from the variation then produce the new array. If you show an attempt i'll post my answer.

Comment: Hey @Matt thanks for the information i was expecting this not the whole code to write i got the answer and i don't need to use loop too :)

Comment: @sAnS if you have answered your own question i'd be good to post what worked for you so anyone who has a similar issue and comes across this post can see what you did.

Comment: @Matt i think better i should not  put since nobody is doing coding service here as mentioned by my dearest fellow SO members so better if some body need let him ask with some down cheering votes :)

Comment: @sAnS they are correct, SO is for fixing bugs, fixing an error in code and all you have shown is the idea. A very thought out idea so i'm surprised you needed to ask SO in the first place. On the flip side, you have an answer so it's best to share and similarly i'll share my version. But in the future you need to show what you have done and attempted, coding wise not theoretically, before people will help.

Comment: @Matt I am posting the answer .. post your too...

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure what you mean by *rest 38 element in a new array randomly* e.g. does this mean the new array is also shuffled? This is what I came up with.

```
<?php

function splitArray($variation, $array) {

    $count = count($array); // Count the elements in the given array
    $removeNumber = floor($count*($variation/100)); // Calculate the number of elements to remove

    // Create an array holding the index numbers for splicing, these numbers are random.
    for($i=0; $i<$removeNumber; $i++) {
        $removeArray[] = rand(0,$count-1);
    }

    // Loop through the removeArray to retrieve the indexes to splice at.
    for($i=0; $i<count($removeArray); $i++) {
        $subArray[] = $array[$removeArray[$i]];
        array_splice($array, $removeArray[$i], 1);
    }

    // return the newly spliced array and the spliced items array
    return array($array, $subArray);

}

$oldArray = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11',
    '12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24',
    '25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35',
    '36','37','38','39','40');

$array = splitArray(5, $oldArray);
$subArray = $array[0];
$newArray = $array[1];
```

Comment: I need both arrays that's why did n't use function figuring out for that..

Comment: @sAnS when you say both, what do you mean? Array of the removed items as well? Can easily add that to the function but you have what works for you so that's good.

Comment: @sAnS I changed it for having both the split array and the split items array :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function subtractFromArray($array,$percentage){
//Randonmising the array
shuffle($array);

//percentage numeric equivalent wrt array aize
$substract_variation_count = floor(sizeof($array) * $percentage/100);

//New extracted array
$new_array = array_slice($array,$substract_variation_count);

//retuns the new array with 38 elements
return $new_array;

}

//array with all elements
$array = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11',
'12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24',
'25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35',
'36','37','38','39','40');

//get new array
$new_array = subtractFromArray($array,5);
//print new array
print_r($new_array);

//Substracted array with 2 elements
$substrcated_array = array_diff($array,$new_array);
print_r($substrcated_array);

?>
```